# Linq subset from two lists of longs

Tags: linq

Given two lists (IList) A and B. I would like to use linq to determine the values of A that are in B. Is this fairly straight forward and efficient? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is the intersection of A and B, so you can use the `Intersect` method:

```
var C = A.Intersect(B);
```